# Обработка больших объемов данных C#

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с проблемой обработки и хранения больших объемов данных. Пишу исследовательское приложение, в задачи которого входит систематизация и обработка статистических данных. Исходный файл, содержащий собственно данные, представляет из себя бинарник, достигающий 1Гб в размере. После расфасовки данных в классы объем памяти, требуемый для хранения всех загруженных данных, может увеличиться до нескольких гигабайт. Но это так... для затравки =) В действительности же все еще хуже. Теоретически объем данных, который необходимо обрабатывать, может достигать таких размеров, что эти данные в принципе невозможно хранить в ОП.

Примером операции обработки может служить операция построения спектра на основе исходных данных, причем построение спектра не должно занимать более 2-3 сек. Т.е. необходимо извлечь данные из хранилища, сделать из них выборку и построить из выбранных данных спектр.

Пытался решить задачу двумя способами:

1. Хранить данные на ЖД и делать выборку в ОП только необходимых в данный момент данных (прошу прощения за неблагозвучность).
2. Вносить все данные в базу данных и делать выборки оттуда.

Первый способ в качестве плюсов имеет быструю скорость внесения записей в импровизированную "базу", но скорость выборок оставляет желать лучшего. Да и постоянная перекачка данных из ОП на ЖД и обратно, при объемах перекачиваемых данных сопоставимых с объемом ОП, провоцирует сбои в работе программы, вплоть до ее зависания.

Со вторым способом все наоборот. Прекрасно работают выборки, но время внесения данных в базу может достигать 3-ех минут (единовременно в базу необходимо вносить порядка 25к записей). Такое время совершенно неприемлемо.

Теперь о средствах проектирования. Приложение разрабатывается на C# в Visual Studio. Базу использовал MS-скую. Пробовал работать с базой через ORM и без него, нужных результатов не добился. Приложение работает в пределах одного ПК, данные поступают извне по Ethernet.

Какие средства можно использовать для быстрой обработки объемных данных?

Comment: _"Исходный файл, содержащий собственно данные, представляет из себя бинарник, достигающий 1Гб в размере."_ -- данные в exe/dll-файле? _"После расфасовки данных в классы"_ -- т.е. все данные десериализуете?

Comment: _"время внесения данных в базу может достигать 3-ех минут"_-- в базу в sql server? как происходит внесение? что для это используете?

Comment: Файл закодирован в нераспространенном формате. Этот файл генерирует специфичное оборудование, предоставляющее статистические данные.Под расфасовкой я подразумевал именно чтение и расшифровку данных из этого файла. Десериализации не происходит.

Comment: Да, данные так долго вносятся в sql server. Использовал Entity Framework 6.0 и пытался писать сам инсерты, в обход ORM. С EF даже не дождался завершения внесения записей, а вот если самописным инсертом вставлять, то ~3 минуты. Все записи вставлялись одним инсертом, объединенные посредством UNION ALL.

Comment: @SoulMicro, для этого `BULK INSERT` обычно используют. В частности, в .NET есть удобная стандартная обёртка для него - `SqlBulkCopy`. С его помощью спокойно можно загружать в SQL Server гиганские объемы(хоть сотни терабайт)  данных, со скоростью фактически не отличающейся от скорости чтения/записи с диска(построение индексов и проверки ограничений проходят пост-фактум, уже после загрузки всех данных, тоже пакетно в фоне).

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, да, сравнительная таблица в 5-ом пункте [статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/251397/) впечатляет! Не могли бы вы добавить упоминание о SqlBulkCopy в свой ответ, если это поможет, я помечу его как решение?

Comment: @SoulMicro _"Использовал Entity Framework 6.0 и пытался писать сам инсерты, в обход ORM"_ -- используйте SqlBulkCopy. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/490270/196972)

Comment: @SoulMicro, добавил

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

1 ГБ данных можно перенести в SQL Server Compact - бесплатная встраиваемая БД.   Вся база поместится в одном sdf-файле (максимальный размер - 4 ГБ).
Для загрузки данных можно использовать [SqlCeBulkCopy](http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/). Примерная скорость загрузки:

```
1 000 000 rows: 6 seconds = 166 666 rows/second
5 000 000 rows: 28 seconds = 178 000 rows/second
```

Также для загрузки данных в sdf можно использовать ExecuteResultSet.
Пример на C# - [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/490304/196972).

Для быстрой выборки необходимых данных, а также для сохранения изменений, можно использовать [SqlCeDataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcedataadapter(v=vs.100).aspx).

Для вывода графиков можно использовать Chart.
Ниже скриншот вывода более 100 тыс. координат.
Создание и вывод происходит достаточно быстро. Пример на C# - [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/490365/196972).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Посмотрите в сторону систем аналитики - Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services, Mondrian, Jedox.

Уж больно сильно выполняемые ими задачи схожи с вашей.

Насчет C# - можете использовать LINQ или MDX работы с ними, прямо в своём приложений.

Для быстрой же вставки больших объемов данных  в SQL Server обычно используют `BULK INSERT`. В частности, в .NET есть удобная стандартная обёртка для него - SqlBulkCopy. С его помощью спокойно можно загружать в SQL Server гиганские объемы(хоть сотни терабайт) данных, со скоростью фактически не отличающейся от скорости чтения/записи с диска(построение индексов и проверки ограничений проходят пост-фактум, уже после загрузки всех данных, тоже пакетно в фоне)

Comment: Использование BulkCopy действительно серьезно ускорило вставку записей в БД. И для дополнительного ускорения уже хотел было "скрещивать ежа с ужом"... Но оказалось, что эта схема увеличивает время первой выборки из базы. И вот теперь узким местом программы является именно эта выборка.

В любом случае, спасибо за подсказку! Буду смотреть на другие предложенные варианты.

Answer (score 1):

Я для хранения данных использовал [Кассандру](http://cassandra.apache.org) Плюсы - быстрая вставка, минус - не совсем быстрая выборка, для каждого критерия выборки нужен свой индекс, без чего хорошо обходится MSSQL, ест много места.

Обработка данных можно осуществить в потоковом режиме, паралельно, частями для этого я использовал [Шторм](http://storm.apache.org). Плюсы - параллелизм обработки, гибкость, наличие статистических библиотек, Минусы - Java (если ты программист не только С# то это не минус) Я знаю Java не очень хорошо, но свою задачу решил. Как вариант можно делать обработку данных на Python или Cloujure

Kaк буфер, можно использовать [сервер очередей](http://kafka.apache.org) Сервером очередей может быть любой сервер, а можно и без него, я просто не знаю, как происходит прием потоковых данных.

Есть еще стек [Hadoop Streaming](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html), но он более тяжелый.

Для статистического анализа, не потокового (исследовательского), можно использовать [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29), а потом, когда определился с обработкой - переписать на python или java.

Удачи в изучении новых технологий.