# Добавление несколько сотен записей в БД за один раз

Tags: c#, sql-server

Какие способы есть и какой самый лучший (или быстрый) для добавления несколько сотен записей в БД за один раз?

Comment: `SqlBulkCopy` ([ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ex21zs8x.aspx)), или [вот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/490269/193999).

Answer (score 1):

Размер пакета (`BatchSize`) обычно стоит подбирать хотя бы эмпирически.

```
    using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default))
    {
      bulkCopy.BatchSize = 100;
      bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = SourceDataTableName;
      try
      {
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(AsDataTable(tableData));
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
        connection.Close();
        throw;
      }
    }
```

Метод AsDataTable позволяет простой лист объектов засунуть легко в базу, не знаю, надо ли вам такое

```
public static System.Data.DataTable AsDataTable<T>(List<T> data)
{
  var properties = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

  var table = new System.Data.DataTable();
  foreach (System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
    table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
  foreach (T item in data)
  {
    var row = table.NewRow();
    foreach (System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
      row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
    table.Rows.Add(row);
  }
  return table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать хранимые процедуры. Такая процедура будет получать параметры, а в её теле вы сможете делать с ними что угодно sql кодом.

Скриншот - https://yadi.sk/i/4tYyEgRmpnpE3

И если в качестве параметра приходит таблица, её можно прямо заливать через select/insert

```
insert into test_tb(par1, par2, par3)
   select td.par1, td.par2, td.par3 from @test_data td
```